# Limit number of bytes written in a PrintStream

Tags: java, security

I'm running some unsecure code which I have set its `stdout` and `stderr` streams to `FileStream`s wrapped in `PrintStream`s. (Standard output/error MUST be redirected.)

Is there any way to configure those redirected `FileStream`s/`PrintStream`s to set a maximum of say 10 MB written, so that, for example,

```
while (true) System.out.write("lots of bytes");
```

doesn't write excessive amounts of data to the server's disk.

The code *does* have a time limit of 15s, but I'd like a separate guard here.

Comment: Just don't subclass `FileOutputStream`. (How are you limiting the time for unsecure code?)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline What's wrong with subclassing `FileOutputStream`? (I'm using @Vlad's solution but…); and I'm just using a BASH script.

Comment: Someone may come along and add an extra method, allowing naughty code to go around your overrides. (Also watch out for integer overflows.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to define a [`FilterOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) that you wrap the file stream in, which keeps an internal counter that it increments on every `write`, and after reaching a set threshold, starts throwing `Exceptions` or simply ignores the writes.

Something along the lines of:

```java
import java.io.*;
class LimitOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream{

    private long limit;

    public LimitOutputStream(OutputStream out,long limit){
        super(out);
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void write(byte[]b) throws IOException{ 
        long left = Math.min(b.length,limit);
        if (left<=0)
            return;
        limit-=left;
        out.write(b, 0, (int)left);
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException{
        if (limit<=0)
            return;
        limit--;
        out.write(b);
    }

    public void write(byte[]b,int off, int len) throws IOException{
        long left = Math.min(len,limit);
        if (left<=0)
            return;
        limit-=left;
        out.write(b,off,(int)left);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar task but reading InputStreams from a DB and made a small method. 
Don't want to be the Captain Obvious but it also can be used with inpustreams like `FileInputStream` too :)

---

```
public static void writeBytes2File(InputStream is, String name,long limit) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[8192];
    int len = 0;
    long size = 0;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(name);  
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            size += len;
            if (size > limit*1024*1024) {
                System.out.println("The file size exceeded " + size + " Bytes ");
                break;
            }
        }   
        System.out.println("File written: " +name);
    }
catch (FileNotFoundException fnone) {
    fnone.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(is!=null){is.close();}
            if (fos != null) {fos.flush();fos.close();
            }       
        } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }        
}
```

---

hope somebody might find it useful.